# Multiple producers- consumers with semaphores: idea for the solution

Tags: unix, synchronization, producer-consumer

I am trying to solve the multiple producers/consumer problem with semaphores.
I solved the problem with multiple producers/consumers for one particular case- when the size of the `buffer` is 1. However, I am having trouble to find out what modifications should I do to my code to solve the problem when the size of the buffer is greater than 1 and there are still a number of producers and consumers.

**Working solution when buffer size = 1**
Here is the pseudo-code of my working solution when the size of the `buffer` is 1.(the code uses a library called `libIPC` that is not very popular, so I pose the pseudo code)

Shared memory is:

```
typedef struct {
 int buffer;//the buffer size is 1,so it is only one integer
 int nbconsumers;  
//shared counter between all processes indicating the number of consumers that read the message
} t_segpart;

t_segpart *sp;
```

I use 3 semaphores, described below:

```
sem_t* sem_produce ;
// semaphore blocking the producers when the buffer is full
sem_t* sem_consumer[NR] ;
// semaphore blocking the consumers when there is no message in the buffer
sem_t* mutex ;
// Mutual exclusion semaphore for protected access to nbconsumers
```

`producer` code:

```
while(1)
{
        P(sem_producer);//producer demands a permission to write in the buffer
        Produce the message in the buffer
        for each consummer i
        V(sem_consumer[i]);//Give access to consumers so that the can read the buffer
 }
```

`consumer` code is:

```
while(1)
    {
        ind = index_consumer(id);
        P(sem_consumer[ind]);//the receiver wants a permission to read the message 
        P(mutex);
        read the buffer
        sp->nbconsumer++;//upgrade nbconsummer
        if(all consumers have read the message)
        {
                V(sem_produce);//Give access to producers so that they can produce a new message in the buffer
                sp->nbconsumer = 0;// nobady has read yet the new buffer
        }
        V(mutex);
}
```

This solution works fine for this particular case when the buffer size is 1.
Can you please tell me how to modify it so that it works for bigger size of the buffer? What semaphores should I introduce? Are there any changes that I should make to the shared memory? For example, I think that the `buffer` will no longer be simple `int variable`, but an `array of int`.
Can you please give a pseudo-code of the case when buffer size is greater than 1?

Comment: What are you going to do when you run on more machines? Shouldn't you make a central dispatch server handling synchronization issues?

Comment: I don't understand very well your question. I am doing a simplified version of the problem where consumers and producers are simple processes made with fork. I will never run on more machines.I am trying to solve the problem on one single pc.

Comment: Forget my question. I was thinking about "Kafka", a distributed messaging system using producers and consumers.

Comment: Can someone describe me the general idea to solve the problem?